# How to make a slider element that hide/shows other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed footer and I am looking for ways to have buttons that behave like so:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|BackButton                     SliderButton ShareButton1 ShareButton3 ShareButton4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The back button is positioned on the left of the footer, while the other buttons are positioned to the right of the footer.

What I attempting to accomplish is the SliderButton action. I need it to behave like so: when clicked hide the share buttons by having a sliding right animation within the footer, so that when clicked it looks like below (note: the ... are just spaces, not actual dots). Also, after this action is complete, you should be able to click on the SliderButton and it should slide to the left, thus showing the ShareButtons once again.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|BackButton . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . SliderButton |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using CSS, Javascript, jQuery, HTML for this task; however I am struggling on the slider button part. I have tried many different methods (using the animate function) but nothing works the way I need it to. It could be due to my markup or due to my HTML arrangement, I am not sure; that is why I have not included my code here so that I can learn from the answers to this question without being biased by my own work.

Comment: _I have tried many different methods_ Where are them? Show us.

Comment: Can you post you html codes and js codes? A more effective way is to make a fiddle of all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/tquLww3h/**

Gotta go, but you can do something like in my fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slide').click(function(){
        $('.social').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will move the SliderButton to the right.

*As I dont know your element names I am assuming random variable names*

```
#axis:hover .move-right{
    transform: translate(350px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -o-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Firefox **/
}
```

Comment: No problems :) but I still haven't figured out what is wrong with this code :/

Comment: Plagiarized from here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/css3-transitions-and-transforms-from-scratch--webdesign-4975